# Синхронизация данных при помощи аккаунта Google

Tags: android, синхронизация

Есть приложение, которое сохраняет пользовательские данные в кеш (позиции пары массивов) и восстанавливает их при повторном запуске приложения.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, **каким образом можно настроить синхронизацию кеша с аккаунтом Google для последующего их восстановления в приложении после, например, переустановки оного**?

Читал про Firebase - это ли мне нужно?

Comment: Можете сохранять данные на Google Drive https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro Здесь вводный курс..

Comment: Вообще для приватных данных приложения работает бэкап из коробки: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup . Единственное но - делается это только когда на устройстве включена синхронизация.

Comment: Нашел в манифесте android:allowBackup="true". Я может не так объяснил в вопросе - концепция в том, чтобы после удаления приложения и повторной его установки из Google Play, автоматически возвращались на место позиции массива.

Comment: В кэш или область настроек? Это разные места для разных целей. В кэш никакие настройки не надо сохранять.

Comment: В кэш. Использую TinyDB для сохранения и восстановления данных массива при выходе-открытии приложения.

Comment: Может сначала нужно сконвертировать данные TinyDB в, например, csv, откуда уже можно будет читать данные для восстановления?